# Copy the values from the next row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, data-cleaning

I have a data frame. There are multiple rows with the same email id. I wanted to copy the values from the next row (second/consecutive) , only for the columns in the first row is empty, for the same email id.

Lets say i have a data frame.

[input df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NMTy.png)

So, now i tried to check if the email id of two consecutive rows are same, and then copy the values from the second row if the first row of the columns are empty.

```
if df['EMAIL'][i]==df['EMAIL'][j+1]:                     
            #df.loc[big_df['NAME'][i].isnull(), 'Y'] = big_df['NAME'][j+1]
            df['NAME'][i].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
            j=j+1
else:
            print('noting to do')
```

I tried the above code and got an error as follows.

```
Attributerror: 'float' object has no attribut 'fillna'
```

I am looking for the output as given below:
[output df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib7qw.png)

Comment: make example text or code not image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `df.groupby(['NAME', 'EMAIL'])['MOBILE'].bfill()`, see duplicate with `bfill` in place of `ffill`. See the second link for an alternative logic.

Comment: @mozway I need to group using EMAIL and copy the NAME and MOBILE.

Comment: Then change the group and slice, still the same logic ;) `df.groupby('EMAIL')[['NAME', 'MOBILE']].bfill()`